# Place question mark submit button inside input field

Tags: html, css, input

I have an input field and a submit button which looks like a question mark due to css styling. This is what it currently looks like:

[image]

How can I position the question mark inside the input field like this:

[image]

HTML

```
<div class="div">
  <form method="post">
    <input type="text" class="input">
    <input type="submit" value="?" class="submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.div {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(50%);
}

.input {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
}

.submit {
  background: none;
  border: none;
}
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/TheCodesee/8h72tjcL/2/

Comment: I'd strongly suggest that you *don't* remove the default styling of the `<input>` element, unless you're creating your own custom styles, otherwise there's nothing to visually indicate that the '?' character is clickable. As for sitting them next to each other? Remove the `display: block;`

Comment: @DavidThomas I suppose I could add a `cursor: pointer` to it

Comment: You could, but then you're just hoping that the user happens to move the cursor over the extremely small `<input>` element. And what about users that navigate with their keyboards?

Comment: @DavidThomas I understand it's not ideal in some cases, but this is what I would like

Answer (score 0):

You could use the question mark as a background image in the input field with some CSS, e.g.:

```
.form-input {
  padding-right: 4rem;
  background-image: url(your image);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center right 1rem;
  background-size: 2rem 2rem;
}
```

You may need to adjust the numbers depending on your image size of course. Your submit button may still exist, but you want to hide (via `visibility` or `display`). Thus, the use can still hit enter to submit the form. 
Another possibility would be to auto submit the form on input blur.

Like that, you can avoid moving the button itself around.

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question, it's more of a work-around. With your solution, there will be no submit button at all.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I missed that you want to move the submit button into your input.

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: absolute` on your submit input.

```css
.div {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(50%);
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.input {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.submit {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  outline: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div">
  <form method="post">
    <input type="text" class="input">
    <input type="submit" value="?" class="submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, I don't see how you can achieve this without absolute positioning or any similar method. What's the matter ?

Comment: I have slightly updated the code in my post. Please check it out and if possible, update your answer

Comment: Updated with your current code but the input text must have a 100% width for the `right` property working properly.